# SVG: Can I reference the same element/group/path instead of copying it multiple times?

Tags: graphics, svg

I'm working on some graphics for a small game.  The graphics will be SVG and will be mostly tile-based (think Legend of Zelda: Link to the Past for SNES).  I've drawn a small grass tile and would like to copy this NxM times over a whole field.  Doing this in Inkscape or another GUI SVG-editing tool results in a file that's over 3.5MB, larger than a 32-bit bitmap of the same dimensions.

I'd like to know if it's possible to define a "grass tile" object of some kind, and instead of copying it to each spot in my field, simply reference it with the appropriate coordinates.  I realize that this will still result in the scene taking up the same amount of memory when loaded, but it will mean much smaller files for storage on disc, and hopefully it will mean easier editing since in this case, if I want to change, for example, the color of my grass, I only have to change my archetype object rather than make the change and then re-copy the new tile over the whole field.

I have done about half a dozen different searches for various keywords that I thought might help, but nothing seems to do what I'm looking for.  I thought to use the 'xlink:href' attribute, as I see this is used in the  tags to define the color palette first, and then reference it later on in a separate tag containing the transform data.

I tried using something like:

`<path id="grassyPatch" d="M 3.3310392e-7,608 31.993091,624 63.986183,608 31.993091,592 z" style="..." />`

And then to copy it with something like:

`<path id="grass-copy1" xlink:href="#grassyPatch" transform="translate(32,-32)" />`
`<path id="grass-copy2" xlink:href="#grassyPatch" transform="translate(32,-64)" />`

etc. in order to copy it several times to new locations.  Appreciate if anyone could let me know if this is possible.  I'm not holding out hope so far, so if you also know it to be *impossible*, please let me know as well so I can stop wasting my time.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, don't forget that SVG is an open standard! [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG10/) is the exact, *official* specification of the format. It is really not that hard to read; much like an API documentation for a file format.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're almost there, the element you're looking for to do copying/cloning is `<use>`

`<use href="#grassyPatch" transform="translate(32,-32)" />`

Comment: Here's a nice guide demonstrating the `<use>` element: http://taye.me/blog/svg/a-guide-to-svg-use-elements/

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned wanting to use GUI tools to accomplish this, so I wanted to let you know that this is possible in Inkscape. You need to use the Clone tool, which is on the toolbar beside the Duplicate tool, or you can press Ctrl-D. When you use it, the clone will be placed directly on top of the object it is cloning. Simply use the move tool to place it where you want it.

Inkscape also has an "Optimized SVG" option in the Save dialog box's filetype dropdown, which will allow you to reduce the filesize of the SVG, by removing extraneous information, as well as optionally reducing precision.

Comment: This is much easier than changing the XML and with much more options. There is also a great guide here: http://www.linuxformat.com/wiki/index.php/Inkscape_-_cloning_and_tiling